# Issue with Cloud Service PaaS VMs

Tags: azure

I have a Cloud Service with 4 Web Role instances (not Cloud Service IaaS VMs). I want to know where / how to configure Load Balancing for these 4 instances. What would be the default LB algorithm, Round Robin?

Actually we faced an issue some time back. We got intermittent failure in our app since we found once instance was taking huge CPU (We got alert). Can we configure load balancer in such a way that it skips the node if the CPU usage goes beyond some threshold?

Answer (score 1):

A custom probe can be configured in your web role's .CSDEF file.  You can write any custom logic that dictates if the service is healthy.

```
<ServiceDefinition …>
   <LoadBalancerProbes>
      <LoadBalancerProbe name="<load-balancer-probe-name>" protocol="[http|tcp]" path="<uri-for-checking-health-status-of-vm>" port=”<port-number>” intervalInSeconds="<interval-in-seconds>" timeoutInSeconds="<timeout-in-seconds>"/> 
   </LoadBalancerProbes>
</ServiceDefinition>
```

Full details: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/azure/jj151530.aspx

Comment: Can not we edit the Load Balancer end points directly as we do in IaaS VMs?